# Using Safe Graphics post installation

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, ubuntu-drivers

I am new to ubuntu, My system is very old so I decided downloading Ubuntu 21.10. I have had a driver issue with my Intel hd 4000 for a while now and seeing "Safe Graphic" mode during installation was life saving for me. The query must be getting clearer to you now, I cant seem to use it after installation and my screen is "green tinted" which was the problem from the start. I wanted to know if there is any workaround for this because I dont wanna go back to Win for MS basic display adapter.

***EDIT:***
Somehow going through recovery mode while booting and then proceeding to a normal boot seems to have worked temporarily, currently my display has no tint and I am kinda happy but I'd love to come across a proper solution to this problem.

Motherboard - A16/06ryx8(Dell inc.),
CPU - i3-3217u,
graphics - intel hd 4000.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1396434/edit) to post more information about your hardware (motherboard, processor, graphics card, etc.)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I did update it, seems like you forgot to revisit it or maybe didnt get notified. I still havent found a workaround and would love some help

Comment: Sorry, I did not get notified. Consider using Xubuntu, it requires a less resource, and may work better on Older computers. You can try the newly released Xubuntu 22.04, since it will be supported for 3 years (until April 2025), unlike 21.10, which will only be supported until July 2022.